# UPDATE and SELECT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

Can anyone help me on how can I update one table having a selection to another table in WHERE clause..

My query is looks like this but it is an error..

```
UPDATE empinfo e SET e.tellno='32154'
 WHERE e.empno IN (SELECT ei.empno FROM empinfo ei WHERE ei.tellno <> '123456');
```

Your response is highly appreciated.. :)

Comment: It'd help a lot if you'd post the error.

Comment: What's the error message that you get? Maybe it's as simple as changing the single quotes into double quotes. :-)

Comment: This is the error message : You can't specify target table 'e' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 7, accepted):

why not:

```
UPDATE empinfo e SET e.tellno='32154' WHERE tellno <> '123456'
```

Answer (score 3):

why do you need nested query here, try directly

```
UPDATE empinfo e SET e.tellno='32154'
WHERE e.tellno != '123456'
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with:

```
UPDATE empinfo e SET e.tellno='32154' WHERE e.tellno <> '123456';
```

or

```
UPDATE empinfo e SET e.tellno='32154' WHERE e.tellno != '123456';
```

or

```
UPDATE empinfo e SET e.tellno='32154' WHERE e.tellno NOT '123456';
```

?
**However**, if empno is not unique in your table then this SQL won't work like the one you've provided! So, is empno unique or not?

Comment: empno there is not a unique value.. is my query will work if the empno is a unique value?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I'm answering this as you acceptence rate is rubbish but here goes.

Try this

```
UPDATE empinfo SET tellno='32154'
WHERE empno IN (
     SELECT empno 
     FROM empinfo 
     WHERE tellno NOT '123456'
);
```

Comment: You can't use a select subquery from the same table that is being updated in a where clause.

Comment: @Eran - You can but not like that. You need to wrap the whole sub query up [as a derived table](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/).

Comment: is it possible to do when you are UPDATING one table then you are going to SELECT on the same table for the WHERE clause of UPDATE query?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, example:

```
REC1: empno=1 tellno='654321'
REC2: empno=2 tellno='654321'
REC3: empno=3 tellno='123456'
REC4: **empno=1** tellno='123456'
```

When you use something like

```
UPDATE empinfo e SET e.tellno='32154' WHERE e.tellno != '123456';
```

Then you will get this:

```
REC1: empno=1 tellno='32154'
REC2: empno=2 tellno='32154'
REC3: empno=3 tellno='123456'
**REC4: empno=1 tellno='123456'**
```

However, your original query seems to want to change it to this:

```
REC1: empno=1 tellno='32154'
REC2: empno=2 tellno='32154'
REC3: empno=3 tellno='123456'
**REC4: empno=1 tellno='32154'**
```

Which of these two options did you want? If you want the second one, then you'll need to do a sub-select but a subselect on the same table isn't possible with MySQL.